# Mozilla deepspeech from deepspeech import Model not working

Tags: model, mozilla-deepspeech, automatic-speech-recognition

Im trying to use mozilla deepspeech to transcribe text however im running into issues importing the Model module.
here is my code

```
from deepspeech.model import model
model_file_path='deepspeech-0.9.3-models.pbmm'
lm_file_path='deepspeech-0.9.3-models.scorer'
beam_width=100
lm_alpha=0.93
lm_beta=1.18
model=Model(model_file_path)
model.enableExternalScorer(lm_file_path)
```

here is the error

```
ImportError: DLL load failed while importing _impl: The specified module could not be found.
```

im using jupytr notebook for context

Answer (score 0):

The issue was the fact that I was using python version 3.10, deepspeech supports python up to version 3.7 so in order to use deepspeech one would need to downgrade the the pythonversion in the environment to 3.7 and below